# Как корректно рулить запросы по версиям

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, phalcon

Вводные:

- nginx
- php-fpm
- framework phalcon

Задача следующая

Рулить запросы /vN/bla-bla в директорию /var/www/app/vN/public/ и деркать там index.php, передавая ему url как аргументы, но уже без префикса /v1, а просто /bla-bla. Где N - любое натуральное число

Тоесть, если приходит на nginx запрос с url /v1/auth, то nginx должен завести запрос в директорию /var/www/app/v1/public/ и выполнить там файл index.php с аргументами /auth

Требование
- должны корректно работать все виды HTTP запросов

Решение

```
location ~* ^/(v\d+)/(.*)$ {
        alias /var/www/app/$1/public/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /$1/index.php?_url=/$2&$args;

        location ~ \.php {
                rewrite ^/(v\d+)/(.*)$ /$2 break;
                include /etc/nginx/includes/api-cross-origin;
                fastcgi_pass docker-fpm-api;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_index /index.php;
                fastcgi_param PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
                fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        }
}
```

Помогите пожалуйста корректно справиться с задачей, так как мне кажется что я не совсем корректно или не до конца решил проблему, ибо опыт работы с подобными вещами у меня только 2 месяца.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Еще вот так работает

```
location ~* ^/(v\d+)/(.*)$ {
        root /var/www/app/$1/public/;
        rewrite ^/(v\d+)/(.*)$ /index.php?_url=/$2&$args break;
        include /etc/nginx/includes/api-cross-origin;
        fastcgi_pass docker-fpm-api-smart-education;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_index /index.php;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```